# Click event not defined via jquery

Tags: datatables-1.10

I have got the following DataTable with data and web bootstrap links displayed via the appropriate columns as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#example').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "ajax":{
                "url":"http://localhost:3000/tasks/list",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns":[
               {"data":"title", "title":"Τίτλος"},
               {"data":"description", "title":"Περιγραφή"},
               { "data": "ID",
                 "title": "Επισκόπηση",
                 "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                    if(type === 'display'){
                         data = '<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm viewlink" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal" href="/tasks/todo/' + data + '">' + '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>' + '</a>';
                    }
                    return data;
                 }
              } ],
             length: 20,
        });



$('.viewlink').on("click", function(e){

        console.log("Hello!!!");

        });

});
```

Unfortunately when i press the bootstrap link button, i do not get any response via console.log.

Any idea that would be convenient to me!

Regards

Comment: put your HTML....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a delegated event handler, i.e

```js
$('#example').on('click', '.viewlink', function(e) {
  //
})
```

Reason: At the time your handler is declared no `.viewLink`'s are present in DOM.